# Predicate insensitive search for two array of strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I am trying to get common values from two array but insensitive match.But cannot succeed.Whats wrong with the predicate.

```
    NSMutableArray *tempArray1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"apple", @"cat", nil];
    NSMutableArray *tempArray2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"APPLE", @"CAT", nil];
   // NSPredicate *resultPredicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN [cd] %@", tempArray1];
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF [cd] IN  %@", tempArray1];
    NSMutableArray *arr_filteredtest = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[tempArray2 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate1]];
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)arr_filteredtest.count);
```

Comment: So if your arrays are `"Cat","Dog","Cow"` and `"CAT","horse"`, your result should be `"Cat","Dog","Cow","horse"`, right?

Comment: I think the correct answer would be `cat` or `CAT`.

Comment: Please clarify: In your example, the common set should have which elements, exactly?

Comment: @ShahiM i want Cat but should not bother case sensiitve

Comment: Is this actually being used with Core Data?

Comment: yes it is being used

Answer (score 0):

If you want case insensitive unique set from your two arrays, first you have to either lowercase or uppercase all the strings, and then create `NSSet` :

```
NSMutableArray *joindArr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray1, nil];
[joindArr addObjectsFromArray:tempArray2];
NSMutableArray *arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //make a nsmutableArray 
for (int i = 0; i<[arr count]; i++) {
    [arr1 addObject:[[arr objectAtIndex:i]lowercaseString]];
}
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:(NSArray*)arr1];//this set has unique values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve intersection using `NSSet`, unfortunately the search using `NSSet` is case sensitive.

1.So convert both the arrays to common case, either `upperCase` or `lowerCase`

2.Use `intersectSet` to get result

**Example:**

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"apple", @"cat", nil];
NSMutableArray *tempArray2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"APPLE", @"CAT", nil];

tempArray2 = [self convertStringObjectsToLoweCase:tempArray2]; //convert all elements to lower case/ upper case
NSSet *set1 = [NSSet setWithArray:tempArray1];
NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithArray:tempArray2];

NSMutableSet *mutableSet = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:set1]; //Initialize with parent array,usually array with more elements
[mutableSet intersectSet:set2];
NSArray *arrayContainingCommonObjects = [mutableSet allObjects];
NSLog(@"arrayContainingCommonObjects : %@",arrayContainingCommonObjects);
```

Use the following helper method

```
- (NSMutableArray *)convertStringObjectsToLoweCase:(NSMutableArray *)inputArray
{
    [inputArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            NSString *loweCaseString = [(NSString *)obj lowercaseString];
            [inputArray replaceObjectAtIndex:idx withObject:loweCaseString];
        }
    }];
    return  inputArray;
}
```

**Output:**

> arrayContainingCommonObjects : (
>       apple,
>       cat )

Answer (score -1):

I think you should to try this one

```
    NSMutableArray *tempArray1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"apple", @"cat", nil];
    NSMutableArray *tempArray2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"apple", @"CAT", nil];
    NSMutableSet *intersection = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:tempArray1];
    [intersection intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:tempArray2]];
    NSArray *NEW_ARR = [intersection allObjects];
    NSLog(@"new arry::  %@",NEW_ARR);
```

Comment: yes,this is a best way to get a common element from two array

Comment: You missed the critical part of the question: *but insensitive match*.